# Winform Drag Drop copy or move depending on destination

Tags: winforms, datagridview, drag-and-drop, copy, move

I would like to implement Drag and Drop between 3 Datagridview dgv1, dgv2 and dgv3.

When DragDrop is performed between dgv1 and dgv2, it would be a move action. Elements in source dgv are deleted and added to destination dgv.

When dragging from dgv1 or dgv2 to dgv3, it would be a copy only. In the reverse direction when dgv3 is source, elements will not be added to dgv1 or dgv2. They would have already existed in either dgv1 or dgv2.

Currently the removal of source element is in source's MouseDown event. How could I manipulate the action depending on the destination dgv ?

```
    private void _columnGrid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Clicks == 1)
        {
            int rowIndex = _columnGrid.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
            if (rowIndex < 0)
                return;

            DragDropEffects dde1 = DoDragDrop(_columnGrid.Rows[rowIndex].DataBoundItem as ItemFormula, DragDropEffects.All);

            if (dde1 == DragDropEffects.All)
            {
                _columnGrid.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
            } 
        }
    }
```

For the first part of the question, when dgv3 is destination, I can achieve by setting DragDropEffect to Copy in dgv3.

```
    private void _lineGrid_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        //copy only
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
```

How about the second part, when I want to drag and drop from dgv3 back to either dgv1 or dgv2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are doing this the wrong way around, let the target's DragDrop event handler do *everything*.  Pass _columnGrid to DoDragDrop() so the target can retrieve it and remove the row.

Comment: Could you clarify? I already pass _columnGrid to DoDragDrop(). _columnGrid is my dgv2 and _lineGrid is dgv3. I would want _columnGrid ->  _lineGrid to copy item from _columnGrid but _lineGrid->_columnGrid to delete or move item from _lineGrid.